Trying to remember a film where a rich risk taker is trying to get life insurance
I think one guy worked for an insurance company, and the other guy (who is some kind of millionaire/CEO of a huge company) wanted to get life insurance, but he was a risk taker and always sky diving or rock climbing or something.
At one point I think they were on a roof talking, and the risk taker runs and jumps off the roof (he is wearing a parachute).
I think it was a comedy, and in the end they end up agreeing to insure the guy. This may not be the entire movie plot, just the part I remember.
I'm sure it was American, and it's been years, but it was quite new when I saw it so I guess it was made in the 2000s. I can't remember who was in it, but I can imagine the risk taker being played by Will Ferrell, and the guy working for the insurance company being played by someone like Paul Rudd.

I believe the film you are looking for is Along Came Polly (2004) a romantic comedy starring Ben Stiller and Jennifer Aniston. Ben Stiller plays a risk assessment specialist for an insurance company. One sub-plot deals with his assessing a rich but high-risk potential client named Leland Van Lew.  
This video link is not the best quality but it was what I could find and shows the scene you describe 



Phillip Seymour Hoffman was genius in that movie.  This is 100% the answer.

IMHO Philip Seymour Hoffman was genius is just about every movie

Yes this is definitely it! Thank you very much.
